# Talking Among GWT Panels using UIBinder Layout

Tags: events, gwt, uibinder

New to GWT here...

I'm using the UIBinder approach to layout an app, somewhat in the style of the GWT Mail sample.  The app starts with a DockLayoutPanel added to RootLayoutPanel within the onModuleLoad() method.  The DockLayoutPanel has a static North and a static South, using a custom center widget defined like:

```
public class BigLayoutWidget extends ResizeComposite {
...
}
```

This custom widget is laid out using BigLayoutWidget.ui.xml, which in turn consists of a TabLayoutPanel (3 tabs), the first of which contains a SplitLayoutPanel divided into WEST (Shortcuts.ui.xml) and CENTER (Workpanel.ui.xml).  Shortcuts, in turn, consists of a StackLayoutPanel with 3 stacks, each defined in its own ui.xml file.

I want click events within one of Shortcuts' individual stacks to change the contents of Workpanel, but so far I've only been able to manipulate widgets within the same class.  Using the simplest case, I can't get a button click w/in Shortcuts to clear the contents of Workpanel or make WorkPanel non-visible.

A few questions...

1. Is ResizeComposite the right type of class to extend for this?  I'm following the approach from the Mail example for TopPanel, MailList, etc, so maybe not?
2. How can I make these clicks manipulate the contents of panels in which they do NOT reside?
3. Are listeners no longer recommended for handling events?  I thought I saw somewhere during compilation that ClickHandlers are used these days, and the click listener "subscription" approach is being deprecated (I'm mostly using @UiHandler annotations)
4. Is there an easy way to get a handle to specific elements in my app/page?  (Applying the "ID" field in the UI.XML file generates a deprecation warning).  I'm looking for something like a document.getElementById() that get me a handle to specific elements.  If that exists, how do I set the handle/ID on the element, and how can I then call that element by name/id?

Note that I have the layout itself pretty well nailed; it's the interaction from one ui.xml modularized panel to the next that I can't quite get.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

1. If you don't have a use for resizing events than just use `Composite`
2. What you want is what the GWT devs called message bus (implemented as [HandlerManager](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.html)). You can get a nice explanation in the widely discussed (for example, on the [GWT Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit), just search for 'mvp') presentation by Ray Ryan from Google I/O 2009 which can be found [here](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html). Basically, you "broadcast" an event on that message bus and then a Widget listening for that event gets the message and does its stuff.
3. Yep, *Handlers are the current way of handling events - the usage is basically the same so migration shouldn't be a problem ([docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiHandlers.html)). They changed it so that they could introduce custom fields in the future, without breaking existing code.
4. If you've set an `id` for any DOM element (for Widgets I use `someWidget.getElement().setId(id)`, usually in combination with [`DOM.createUniqueId()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html#createUniqueId())) you can get it via [`GWT.get(String id)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootPanel.html#get(java.lang.String)). You'll get then a `RootPanel` which you'll have to cast to the right Widget class - as you can see it can get a little 'hackish' (what if you change the type of the Widget by that id? Exceptions, or worse), so I'd recommend sticking with MVP (see the first point) and communicating via the message bus. Remember however, that sometimes it's also good to aggregate - not everything has to be handled via the message bus :)

Bottom line is I'd recommend embracing MVP (and [History](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html)) as soon as possible - it makes GWT development much easier and less messy :) (I know from experience, that with time the code starts to look like a nightmare, if you don't divide it into presentation, view, etc.)